# Reference a jar within a jar

Tags: java, reference, manifest, onejar

I have a jar file that references 6 other jars through a manifest file.

I now, however, want to try and compile the jars into one jar file, reasons being: I want them to be cached so the applet does not have a long loading time as one of those jars are required, rather one big waiting time to download all required files and then store it in the cache.

I have tried including the referenced Jar files in the build, unfortunately, all this does is cause a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error, so I had to add a manifest file.

What is the best/easiest way to achieve this? I am using eclipse, and not building with ant.

Comment: *"I want them to be cached so the applet does not have a long loading time as one of those jars are required"*  That makes little or no sense.  E.G. The 'fat jar' will take 4 times as long to download as the 4 separate Jars.  You would be better off deploying the applet using JWS/JNLP & specifying the other Jars as `lazy` downloads.

Comment: The reason behind this is that the application would be used daily by clients, I want the data to be cached rather than having to download the 2MB every time the application is opened..

Comment: Caching the classes is the **default behavior** of both standard deployed applets *and* JNLP.  This is a non-question.

Answer (score 0):

Using eclipse while exporting you can create with the option of
*Package required libraries into generate JAR*

By doing this eclipse uses its own class loader and reference all the files which are packed in a single jar.

Comment: Infact, it is packeged within the Jar.. But still you must reference it with the Manifest. As soon as the manifest reference is gone I receive the java.lang.NoClassFoundError..

Comment: Note that only a trusted applet can use a custom class-loader.